# Toggle DIVs with JQuery when HTML Form is added within child DIV via .innerhtml()

Tags: jquery, html, forms, toggle

First off, I am sorry if this is a remedial question.  I am very new to JQuery and Javascript in general.

So within my HTML file, I have 2 DIVs that I want to toggle based on a radio button selection within a form

```
<div id = 'mySched'></div>
<div id = 'orView'></div>
```

My form was initially setup within the HTML file, as were the DIVs above:

```
<form>    
<input type='radio' id='userSched' name='viewSelect' value='userSched'> 
<input type='radio' id='orActivity' name='viewSelect' value='orActivity'>  
</form>
```

Initially, I found a very useful JQuery script, which I modified to make this work wonderfully:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#orView").hide();
  $("mySched").show();

  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
   if($(this).attr("value")=="userSched"){
       $("#orView").hide();
       $("#mySched").show();
   }

   if($(this).attr("value")=="orActivity"){
       $("#mySched").hide();
       $("#orView").show();
   }});
  });
```

So, when everything is within the HTML file, it works well....selecting 'userSched' shows the mySched DIV and selecting 'orActivity', hides the mySched DIV and shows the orView DIV.  This is great!

My issue is that I had to make the HTML more dynamic and therefore utilize an external JS file to insert the HTML via .innerhtml().

Therefore, I want to use the exact same DIV names and form names, but now the FORM is defined in my external JS file instead of within the HTML file.  I will now reference the FORM HTML code with the following DIV:

```
<div id ='viewSelector'></div>
```

How can I modify the above JQuery script to properly toggle the two options like before, referencing the FORM that is now nested within the 'viewSelector' DIV??  I am sure this is easy for your JQuery whizzes....I am just clueless on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the selector `input[type="radio"]` to `#viewSelector input[type="radio"]`?

Answer (score 2):

assign event handlers with `.on()` instead of `.click()` if the elements are created dynamically ( if the radio buttons are not there on the initial page load)

actually - realistically , always use `.on()` instead , it's just better

also , use `.val()` instead of `.attr("value")`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#orView").hide();
  $("#mySched").show();   // < there was a bug here , see your code


  $(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
   if($(this).val() =="userSched"){
       $("#orView").hide();
       $("#mySched").show();
   }

   if($(this).val() =="orActivity"){
       $("#mySched").hide();
       $("#orView").show();
   }});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove JQuery ready function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#orView").hide();
      $("#mySched").show();   // < there was a bug here , see your code


      $(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
       if($(this).val() =="userSched"){
           $("#orView").hide();
           $("#mySched").show();
       }

       if($(this).val() =="orActivity"){
           $("#mySched").hide();
           $("#orView").show();
       }});
</script>
```

try it [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vkpham5190/NF6aA/)